# Groupby names replace values with there max value in all columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this DataFrame

```
lst = [['AAA',15,'BBB',20],['BBB',16,'AAA',12],['BBB',22,'CCC',15],['CCC',11,'AAA',31],['DDD',25,'EEE',35]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['name1','val1','name2','val2'])
```

which looks like this

```
 name1   val1 name2 val2
0  AAA     15  BBB   20
1  BBB     16  AAA   12
2  BBB     22  CCC   15
3  CCC     11  AAA   31
4  DDD     25  EEE   35
```

I want this

```
 name1   val1 name2  val2
0  AAA     31  BBB    22
1  BBB     22  AAA    31
2  BBB     22  CCC    15
3  CCC     15  AAA    31
4  DDD     25  EEE    35
```

replaced all values with the maximum value. we choose the maximum value from both `val1` and `val2`

if i do this i will get the maximum from only `val1`

```
df["val1"] = df.groupby("name1")["val1"].transform("max")
```

Comment: shouldn't name2 be strings instead of numbers?

Comment: your input for BBB has val2's of 12 and 15 - why does your output have 31 and 15?

Comment: @HenryYik my bad edited it

Comment: Why are there 2 sets of columns (`name1` and `name2` and `val1` and `val2`)? Is there a good reason why you can't have a single `name` column and a single `val` column?

Comment: @JonClements BBB maximum value from val1 and val2 is 22 so replaced all BBB with 22

Comment: @Ken according to my data i can't do it both have some common names but values should be the max of both columns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `pd.wide_to_long` to melt that dataframe into a long form, then use groupby with transform to find the max value.  Map that max value to 'name' and reshape back to four column (wide) dataframe:

```
df_long = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['name','val'], 'index', j='num',sep='',suffix='\d+')
mapper= df_long.groupby('name')['val'].max()
df_long['val'] = df_long['name'].map(mapper)
df_new = df_long.unstack()
df_new.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i,j in df_new.columns]
df_new
```

Output:

```
      name1 name2  val1  val2
index                        
0       AAA   BBB    31    22
1       BBB   AAA    22    31
2       BBB   CCC    22    15
3       CCC   AAA    15    31
4       DDD   EEE    25    35
```

Answer (score 8):

Borrow Scott's setting up

```
df_long = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['name','val'], 'index', j='num',sep='',suffix='\d+')
d = df_long.groupby('name')['val'].max()

df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('val')]=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('name')].replace(d).values
df
Out[196]: 
  name1  val1 name2  val2
0   AAA    31   BBB    22
1   BBB    22   AAA    31
2   BBB    22   CCC    15
3   CCC    15   AAA    31
4   DDD    25   EEE    35
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `lreshape` (undocumented and ambiguous as to whether it's tested or will continue to remain) to get the long DataFrame, then map each pair of columns using the max.

```
names = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('name')]
vals = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('val')]

s = (pd.lreshape(df, groups={'name': names, 'val': vals})
       .groupby('name')['val'].max())

for n in names:
    df[n.replace('name', 'val')] = df[n].map(s)
```

---

```
  name1  val1 name2  val2
0   AAA    31   BBB    22
1   BBB    22   AAA    31
2   BBB    22   CCC    15
3   CCC    15   AAA    31
4   DDD    25   EEE    35
```

Answer (score 2):

This builds off @ScottBoston's answer :

```
res = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ["name", "val"], "index", j="num")
res.update(res.groupby(["name"]).val.transform("max"))
res = res.unstack()
res.columns = [f"{first}{last}" for first, last in res.columns]
res.rename_axis(index=None)


   name1    name2   val1    val2
0   AAA     BBB     31      22
1   BBB     AAA     22      31
2   BBB     CCC     22      15
3   CCC     AAA     15      31
4   DDD     EEE     25      35
```